# React Connected Component package without host having redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm new to react and I'm trying to create a connected component (redux) for internal use in the company but I don't want to force the host app to have redux. I want to avoid having my component used like this:

```
<Provider store={store}><MyComponent /></Provider>
```

I thought in using something like Higher-Order Components and Contexts, but it is just not clicking.

Even creating my own provider would be acceptable, something like:

```
<MyComponentProvider><MyComponent /></MyComponentProvider>
```

Is it possible for a host application to use a Redux Component without having redux as a dependency?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. What do you want to achieve? Please provide more details

Comment: Imagine I have a combobox component as a NPM package that used redux in the implementation. Can I import and use that combobox component in an application that doesn't have a redux dependency?

Comment: If you are in control of this combobox component, you can simply export the unconnected, original component that only expects a bunch of props to work correctly. Exporting something that requires the provider, context etc. and then wrapping this again doesn't make sense to me. That's two layers of abstraction wrapped around the original thing for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible. The component can have its own redux store. Keep it as a complete black box.

Here is a demo, consider the package directory is your npm package and we install the `redux`, `react-redux` packages in the npm package, not your host or main project.

`package/combobox.tsx`:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export const Combobox = () => {
  const state = useSelector((state) => state);
  console.log('state: ', state);
  return <div>combobox</div>;
};
```

we can wrap it in a special component that initializes the store in the constructor:

`package/index.tsx`:

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import * as React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Combobox } from './combobox';

const reducer = (state = { counter: 1 }) => {
  return state;
};

export default class ComboboxConnected extends Component {
  store: ReturnType<typeof createStore>;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.store = createStore(reducer);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={this.store}>
        <Combobox />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, each `Combobox` component instance has its own redux store and state.

Consumer side
`App.tsx`:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Combobox from './package/index';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Combobox />
    </div>
  );
}
```

See [Isolating Redux Sub-Apps](https://redux.js.org/usage/isolating-redux-sub-apps)

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-yi6crm?file=App.tsx)